# What make http/2 faster than http/1 beyond multiplexing and server push?

Tags: http, http2, http-1.1

I could understand why `multiplexing` and `server push` help speed up web page loading and reduce workload on server side. But I have also learned that `binary protocol`, `header compression`, and `prioritization of requests` also contribute to performance improvements of `http/2` over `http/1`. How do these three features actually contribute to the improvements?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42746364/performance-benefit-of-http-2-over-http-for-single-request/?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Binary protocol**

This actually doesn’t help that much IMHO other than the allowing of [multiplexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36517829/what-does-multiplexing-mean-in-http-2) (which DOES help a lot with performance). Yes it’s easier for a program to parse binary packets than text but I don’t think that’s going to make a massive performance boast. The main reason to go binary, as I say are for the other benefits (multiplexing and header compression) and to make parsing easier, than for performance.

**Header compression**

This can have a big potential impact. Most requests (and responses) repeat a LOT of data. So by compressing headers (which works by replacing repeated headers with references across requests rather than by compressing within requests like HTTP body compression works) [can significantly reduce the size of request](https://blog.cloudflare.com/hpack-the-silent-killer-feature-of-http-2/) (but less so for responses where the headers are often not a significant portion of the total response).

**Prioritisation of requests**

This is one of the more interesting parts of HTTP/2 which has huge potential but has not been optimised for yet. Think of it like this: imagine you have 3 critical CSS files and 3 huge images to download. Under HTTP/1.1, 6 connections would be opened and all 6 items would download in parallel. This may seem fine but it means the less critical image files are using up bandwidth that would be better spent on the critical CSS files. With HTTP/2 you can say “download the critical CSS first with high priority and only when they are done, look at those 3 image files”. Unfortunately, despite the fact that HTTP/2 has a prioritisation model that allows as complex prioritisation as you want (too complex some argue!) [browsers and servers don’t currently use it well](https://twitter.com/patmeenan/status/1065275742483824642?s=21) (and website owners and web developers currently have very little way to influence it at all). In fact bad prioritisation decisions can actually make HTTP/2 slower than HTTP/1.1 as the 6 connection limit is lifted and hundreds of resources can all download in parallel, all fighting over the same bandwidth. I suspect there will be a lot more research and change here in implementations, but there shouldn’t need to be much change in the spec as it already allows for very complex prioritisation as I mentioned.

We’ve been optimising for HTTP/1.1 for decades and have squeezed a lot out of it. I suspect we’ve a lot more to get out of HTTP/2 (and HTTP/3 when it comes along too). Check out my [upcoming book](https://www.manning.com/books/http2-in-action) if interested in finding out more on this topic.